# How to run my function in thread every 5 minutes | Python |

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, mongodb, python-multithreading

I am trying to write a code where my `function` should run every 5 minutes `ON` and `OFF`

**Means like :** first 5 minutes it will run and next 5 minutes will be on sleep and again run

Need to achieve using **Threading**

So that I will have control to handle the **Thread killing** as an when required.

I am trying to store the function return `message` , `start time` and `end time` to Mongo DB

**My code :**

```
import threading
import pymongo as pymongo
import datetime
import json

dbUrl = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:5600/")
dbName = dbUrl["ABC"]
dbCollectionName = dbName["Demo"]


def hello_world():
    global kill_the_running_thread
    while (not kill_the_running_thread):
        msg="Hello"
        note_start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        print(msg)
        note_end_time   = datetime.datetime.now()
        dt = {msg,note_start_time,note_end_time}
        r = json.dumps(dt)
        loaded_r = json.loads(r)
        rec_id1 = dbCollectionName.insert_one(r)
        dt = {}

def main():

    global kill_the_running_thread
    kill_the_running_thread = False
    my_thread = threading.Thread(target=hello_world())
    my_thread.start()

    input("Press enter to kill the running thread : ")
    kill_the_running_thread = True

# Calling main
main()
```

**When I am running my code getting below error**

```
TypeError: Object of type set is not JSON serializable
Hello
```

Any solution is much appreciated !!!

Comment: You are trying to serialize a `set` object `dt` into `json` string. You can do something like `dt={"message":msg, "start_time": note_start_time, "end_time": note_end_time}` and it should work.

Comment: And running your code every 5 minutes, there are several ways of achieving this. Either you can use a python block scheduler like this: https://github.com/agronholm/apscheduler or even use `while True:` to create infinite loop and call your main function `main()` inside that loop and sleep after every call with `time.sleep(6000)`. Another alternative would be to create cronjob with your python script and run it every 5 mins.